# Simplify trig identity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

So I am having a hard time with this math question:

$$1-2\sin ^2(x)+\sin^4(x)$$

The prompt is to factor the trigonometric equation and simplify. I get it simplified to a point but the answer I keep getting is:

$$(1 + \sin^2(x))(\cos^2(x))$$

For some reason the answer key says the answer is $\cos^4(x)$ but I have no idea how they are getting to that conclusion.

Answer (score 4):

Method-1: 
$$1-2\sin^2 x+\sin^4 x=(1)^2-2(1)(\sin^2 x)+(\sin^2 x)^2$$
By applying $a^2-2ab+b^2=(a-b)^2$
$$=(1-\sin^2 x)^2$$
$$=(\cos^2 x)^2$$
$$=\color{red}{\cos^4 x}$$

Method-2: 
$$1-2\sin^2 x+\sin^4 x=1-\sin^2 x-\sin^2 x+\sin^4 x$$
$$=(1-\sin^2 x)-\sin^2 x(1-\sin^2 x)$$
$$=\cos^2 x-\sin^2 x(\cos^2 x)$$
$$=\cos^2 x(1-\sin^2 x)$$
$$=\cos^2 x(\cos^2 x)$$
$$=\color{red}{\cos^4 x}$$

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* $1-2\sin^2(x)+\sin^4(x)=(1-\sin^2(x))^2$

Comment: This is obviously the part that the asker was stuck with, how does this help them understand how to solve this problem? Giving a hint like this doesn't teach them anything, it just let's them find the answer to this question specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try!

Let $\sin^2 x = u$

then, 
$$1 - 2\sin^2 x + \sin^4 x= 1 - 2u + u^2 =(1 -  u)^2$$

Substituting the trig function back in:

$$(1 -  u)^2 = (1 - \sin^2 x)^2 = (cos^2 x)^2 $$ 
**$$=\cos^4 x$$**